# How can I specify a domain x-axis in NVD3 lineChart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to define a lineChart in nvd3 with a domain scale on the x-axis.  I can't get it to work.  The first issue is that the voronoi code blows up.  But even if I turn voronoi off, the x-axis still just shows a range of -1 to 1, instead of my domain values.

I think a workaround would be to assign numbers to the x-axis values, and then use a tick function to draw the text.  But I want to figure out why I can't make it work with an ordinal scale.

Below is the code I have tried.  My data works with other models, so I think the data is ok.  I tried using the xDomain function to set the domain, and I also tried using the xAxis property to set a custom scale.  Neither one seemed to do anything.

Code:

```
var lineData = [{ "key": "% Kernel CPU", "values": [{ "x": "Exe1", "y": 6.693271 }, { "x": "Exe2", "y": 0.8129451 }, { "x": "Exe3", "y": 71.3511437 }] },
            { "key": "% User CPU", "values": [{ "x": "Exe1", "y": 93.7063302 }, { "x": "Exe2", "y": 23.158042000000002 }, { "x": "Exe3", "y": 74.19397850000001 }] }];
        var xdomain = ["Exe1", "Exe2", "Exe3"];

        $('#test').append('<svg style="width:100%;height:400px;"></svg>');

        nv.addGraph(function () {
            var chartObj = nv.models.lineChart();
            chartObj.lines.scatter.useVoronoi(false);

            chartObj.xAxis.tickFormat(function (d) {
                if (d.length > 15) {
                    return d.substring(0, 13) + '...';
                }
                return d;
            });

            chartObj.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format('.1f'));

            //Attempt1:
            chartObj.xDomain(xdomain);
            //Attempt2: 
            //var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal();
            //xScale.domain(xdomain);
            //chartObj.xAxis.scale(xScale);
            //Attempt3:
            //chartObj.xAxis.domain(xdomain);

            d3.select('#test svg').datum(lineData)
                       .transition().duration(500).call(chartObj);
            return chartObj;
        });
```

Comment: Have you tried `chartObj.xAxis.domain(xdomain)`?

Comment: I just tried that, and I get the same result.  The xAxis scale is still -1 to 1, and no data is visible.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in these lines in the models.scatter definition:

```
  if ( isNaN(x.domain()[0])) {
      x.domain([-1,1]);
  }

  if ( isNaN(y.domain()[0])) {
      y.domain([-1,1]);
  }
```

Obviously this will disallow any ordinal scales for the x or y scales in this type of chart (which underlies the line chart and most of the other non-bar charts it seems).